# Azure API Management Policy - Dynamic named value select

Tags: azure-api-management, policy

I have stored a named value based on the user id, so I can identify the payload submitter, with a reference of my choosing.

When I use the policy below, I get the value as a string, rather than actually looking up the named value. If I simply write the user id inside the double curly brackets rather than getting it dynamically from the context, the lookup works fine and it substitues with the named value I want.

Is it not possible to do in a simple manner?

```
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <set-header name="x-request-context-data" exists-action="override">
      <value>{{@(context.User.Id)}}</value>
    </set-header>
  </inbound>
</policies>
```

Output:

```
x-request-context-data: {{@(context.User.Id)}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answered at [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb9702d4-9185-4cb8-8f42-945ff98c3d8b/selecting-named-value-from-context-value-in-inbound-policy).

> While you can use named values in policy expressions, the other way
>   around is not supported and not possible to support as described in
>   this [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/19530124-dynamic-property-references).
>
> Workarounds would be to either
>
> - Store named values as a JSON string or a CSV string with key=value pairs. Then use policy expressions to parse and fetch the required value.
> - Use [control flow policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#choose) for run time decisions.
> - For complex cases, offload to a function app but use [value caching policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies) for improved latency if possible